# Limit law of iterated logarithm

Tags: probability, limits, random-variables, expected-value

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be independent random variables with mean zero, variance one, and a uniformly bounded third absolute moment. Let $ S_k = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_k $ denote their sum. Darling and Erdös (1956) [proved](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-23/issue-1/A-limit-theorem-for-the-maximum-of-normalized-sums-of/10.1215/S0012-7094-56-02313-4.short) that
$$
\max_{1 \leq k \leq n}\frac{|S_k|}{\sqrt{k}} = (1+o(1))\sqrt{2\log\log(n)},
$$
with high probability. My question is whether it's possible to show that
$$
\mathbb{E}\big(\max_{1 \leq k \leq n}\frac{|S_k|}{\sqrt{k}}\big) = (1+o(1))\sqrt{2\log\log(n)},
$$
if we assume additionally that the $X_i$ are Gaussian. I've tried the usual trick of first considering the Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process, but I'm still running into trouble. Any help would be much appreciated!